# Making a query dynamically based on a date picker in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to show some data between 2 dates chosen by the user in a date picker but I didn't found a way to write the query right.,always got this error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN2013-04-14AND2013-04-15GROUP BY created_at ORDER BY created_at' at line 1
```

Here is what i wrote so far :

```
$sd=$_POST['sd'];
$ed=$_POST['ed'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(name) As Subscribers,CAST(`created_at` AS DATE) As Date FROM gcm_users WHERE created_at BETWEEN".$_POST['sd']."AND".$_POST['ed']."GROUP BY created_at ORDER BY created_at")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: missing some spaces "BETWEEN2013-04-14AND2013-04-15GROUP"

Comment: try to add a space before `GROUP BY`, and after `BETWEEN`, `AND`...

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* what is wrong. Is not reading or understanding error messages in vogue these days?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add spaces:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(name) As Subscribers,CAST(`created_at` AS DATE) As Date FROM gcm_users WHERE created_at BETWEEN '".$_POST['sd']."' AND '".$_POST['ed']."' GROUP BY created_at ORDER BY created_at")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It needs DATE too:
The correct query is :
SELECT count(name) As Subscribers,CAST(`created_at` AS DATE) As Date FROM gcm_users WHERE CAST(`created_at` AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE('".$_POST['sd']."') AND DATE('".$_POST['ed']."') GROUP BY created_at ORDER BY created_at

Comment: @user219241 glad that you figured it out.